# Why are no tests shown on testing overview?

Tags: testing

I want to run [DrupalWebTestCases](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21simpletest%21drupal_web_test_case.php/7) on my custom Drupal 7 module.

Following the Tutorial at https://drupal.org/simpletest-tutorial-drupal7 i'm stuck at running the tests:
also after cache deletion no other Tests than for SimpleTest are found on the `/admin/config/development/testing`-page.

I'm using the contributed SimpleTest module, added the `testing_api = 2.x` setting to my modules .info.

mymodule/mymodule.info:

```
name = Mymodule Reports
core = 7.x
php = 5.3
files[] = tests/*.test
testing_api = 2.x
```

mymodule/tests/mymodule.test:

```
/**
 * @file
 * Mymodule reports module tests.
 */

class MymoduleReportsTestCase extends DrupalWebTestCase {

  public static function getInfo() {
    return array(
      'name' => 'MymoduleReports',
      'description' => 'Ensure that the locking of nodes functions properly.',
      'group' => 'Mymodule',
    );
  }

}
```

What i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you for your comment - i added the modules .info and testfile.

Comment: *ARGH* while inserting the code i saw that i used `files[] = tests/*.test` what i've seen in one example but inserting the actual filename it's working now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using

```
files[] = tests/*.test
```

in mymodule/mymodule.info
it should be

```
files[] = tests/mymodule.test
```